# Translate not working in jQuery message

Tags: magento2

I have a store with 2 languages arb and eng and I added validation in number and I add ar_Sa.csv but it does not convert when I change the store to Arabic. It shows the same in English.
Below is my code

```
            $.validator.addMethod(
                'mobile_ksa', function (phone_number, element) {
                    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
                        phone_number.match(/^(05)(5|0|3|6|4|9|1|8|7)([0-9]{7})$/);
                }, $.mage.__('invalid phone number'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in magento 2. You have to delete the `js-translation.json` from ‘pub/static/frontend/Magento/[theme]/[lang_code]/‘ then do run ‘setup:static-content:deploy [language_code]’

Let me know